# Cumulative distribution function for Compton scattering

Tags: scattering-cross-section

Just for reference, this is the cross section for Compton scattering.

$$
\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}
\propto\left(\frac{E'}{E}\right)^2\left(\frac{E'}{E}+\frac{E}{E'}-\sin^2\theta\right)
$$

Currently I am integrating $d\sigma$ numerically to obtain scattering
probabilities per angular bin.
However, numerical integration would not be necessary if I had
a cumulative distribution function.

Is there a closed form cumulative distribution function for Compton scattering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noting that $d\Omega=\sin\theta\,d\theta\,d\phi$, we have
$$
d\sigma\propto
\left(\frac{E'}{E}\right)^2
\left(\frac{E'}{E}+\frac{E}{E'}-\sin^2\theta\right)\sin\theta
\,d\theta\,d\phi
$$

Let $g(\theta)$ be the following antiderivative.
$$
g'(\theta)=
\left(\frac{E'}{E}\right)^2
\left(\frac{E'}{E}+\frac{E}{E'}-\sin^2\theta\right)\sin\theta
$$

Then
\begin{multline*}
g(\theta)=-\frac{\cos\theta}{R^2}
+\log\bigl(1+R(1-\cos\theta)\bigr)\left(\frac{1}{R}-\frac{2}{R^2}-\frac{2}{R^3}\right)
\\
{}-\frac{1}{2R\bigl(1+R(1-\cos\theta)\bigr)^2}
+\frac{1}{1+R(1-\cos\theta)}\left(-\frac{2}{R^2}-\frac{1}{R^3}\right)
\end{multline*}

where
\begin{equation*}
R=\frac{E}{mc^2}
\end{equation*}

Then the cumulative distribution function $F(\theta)$ is
$$
F(\theta)=\frac{g(\theta)-g(0)}{g(\pi)-g(0)},\quad0\le\theta\le\pi
$$